# Change color of an asp.net button on mouse hover using css

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a button :

```
<div class="HeaderBarThreshold">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="SetThreshold" OnClick="btnSetThreshold_Click" runat="server">Threshold</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the color of the button on mouse hover :

Here is my css :

```
.HeaderBarThreshold
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.HeaderBarThreshold:hover
{
    color: Red;      
}
```

It doesnt work somehow. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this

```
.HeaderBarThreshold:hover a
{
     color: Red !important; // !important may not be necessary 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the CssClass Property of ASP.NET controls.  This will directly point the LinkButton itself to the CSS class, instead of having to use the div tag. For example:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SetThreshold" OnClick="btnSetThreshold_Click" runat="server" CssClass="HeaderBarThreshold">Threshold</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the CSS class attribute to your web control

```
<asp:LinkButton CSSClass="HeaderBarThreshold" ID="SetThreshold" OnClick="btnSetThreshold_Click" runat="server">Threshold</asp:LinkButton>
```

Also your CSS is wrong anyway because you don't have anything assigned to class "HeaderBarThreshold".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zpfw7/

```
    .HeaderBarThreshold
    {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .HeaderBarThreshold:hover
    {
    color: Red; 
    background:blue;
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for an ASP.NET web form in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 1):

try this thing:

```
.HeaderBarThreshold a:hover
{
    color: Red;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.upda_link {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.upda_link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="upda_link" CausesValidation="false">
</asp:LinkButton>
```